# Firebase Multi-location update in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase

I am trying to do a multi-location update in Angular. However, the `.update()` function seems to behave differently than it would on a nodejs server.

```
var updatedUser = { name: 'Shannon', username: 'shannonrules' };
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var fanoutObject = {};

fanoutObject['/users/1'] = updatedUser;
fanoutObject['/usersWhoAreCool/1'] = updatedUser;
fanoutObject['/usersToGiveFreeStuffTo/1'] = updatedUser;

ref.update(fanoutObject); // atomic updating goodness
```

Basically, I get the error:

> Firebase.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key
>   (products_tags/all/all/345).  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't
>   contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

When I apply the same code on a nodejs server, then it works fine.
How can this be overcome?

Comment: That error message happens when you run multi-location updates on a client that doesn't support them. Double-check that you are using version 2.3 or later.

Comment: Lifesaver...! Think this is the first time that I experienced an issue due to version control.